# Receive mail into Gmail from custom domain Google Apps

Tags: gmail, pop3

I have a regular Gmail account and a custom domain'd Gmail account. I want to use Gmail's "Check mail using POP3" function to retrieve the latter into my regular `user@gmail.com` but I can't get past this popup:

[image: Add a mail account, Gmail]

It either says it had a problem connecting to `pop.gmail.com` or `mail.customdomain.com` timed out.

One last note: I do not want to forward emails from one account to another.

Comment: I understand that you would rather not forward emails from one domain to another...but that is dramaticly easyer. (and you can't tell that it is a forward. it looks like it is recived via gmail.com. ) it is much FASTER and easier to refresh.

is there a reason you don't wan't to use the forwarding option?

Comment: Because I want to be able to reply to that emails as if I were logged in into G.Apps. (I do have configured it to send as this second username).
What I mean is, won't forwarding break the conversation flow in my inbox?

Comment: it doesn't for me. it works just as if I recive the message to my native gmail. that how I have it setup and it works great

Comment: Ignacio I've tried both forwarding and pop. To me, the **only real advantage** fetching e-mails have over forwarding is you can easily decide to stop receiving e-mails from the second account by simply deactivating it within your main account. And nothing gets broken in either way. If you ask us 3, that is a **lame advantage** and forwarding has all other advantages: faster to deliver (can't get any faster), cleaner (from looking at the mail source and headers), easier to setup (no passwords or ports needed) and more natural (*forwarding* is basically how mail servers talk among them - SMTP).

Comment: Thanks, guys, I'll give forwarding a go then and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For gmail, the port should be 995 not 110.
Also you have to make sure that pop is enabled on the account.

However, as mjrider says, forwarding is much faster and it should cause any problems with conversation flow, providing you don't log into the secondary account directly and send emails from there (since these replies won't appear in your main account).

I use both forwarding and pop access, but the latter is only for is an old account which I can't forward.